# What is this tree with round yellow fragrant smelling buds?

Tags: identification, trees

I saw this flowering tree on the Greek Island of Aegina which was very fragrant, with round yellow buds. Picture was taken in February.

[image: plant]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be an Acacia Caven. I'm not sure if a common name is Mimosa for this one

Comment: It is a mimosa, for sure, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimosa